# TypeError: 'module' object is not callable for OpenAI

Tags: artificial-intelligence, google-colaboratory, openai-api

```
import openai as OpenAI 
client = OpenAI()

completion = client.chat.completions.create(
  model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
  messages=[
    {"role": "system", "content": "You are a poetic assistant, skilled in explaining complex programming concepts with creative flair."},
    {"role": "user", "content": "Compose a poem that explains the concept of recursion in programming."}
  ]
)

print(completion.choices[0].message)
```

The response I am getting is

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-6de2ef8831ea> in <cell line: 2>()`your text`
      1 import openai as OpenAI
----> 2 client = OpenAI()
      3 
      4 completion = client.chat.completions.create(
      5   model="gpt-3.5-turbo",

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable`
```

I tried to solve the issue with Google Bard and chat gpt but could not

Answer (score 0):

Update :
I was able to resolve the issue using the

```
client = OpenAI

completion = client.chat.completions.create(
  model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
  messages=[
    {"role": "system", "content": "You are a poetic assistant, skilled in explaining complex programming concepts with creative flair."},
    {"role": "user", "content": "Compose a poem that explains the concept of recursion in programming."}
  ]
)

print(completion.choices[0].message)
```